# Sorting multi column range script

Tags: function, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Here is a **well working** script which :
**1-** Drop a date tag in the cell H (8) for each modification in a row (I know there is something wrong in this command but it does what I am expecting...)
AND
**2-** Sort the whole sheet following this rule :
- column 1 : ascendent,
- column 2 : ascendent,
- column 3 : ascendent and
- column 8 ; descendent.

**Question :**
**1-** how I add a range (A2:K999) to the second order (sorting) ?
**2-** how I add a trigger (button or menu or whatever) to the second command (sorting) ?

Can someone give me a hand ?

```
function onEdit(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh0 = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).setValue(new Date());


 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(); 
dataRange.sort([ 
  {column: 1, ascending: true}, 
  {column: 2, ascending: true}, 
  {column: 3, ascending: true}, 
  {column: 8, ascending: false} ]);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:K999");

function onEdit(e)  {
range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 3, ascending: true}, {column: 8, ascending: false}]);
}
```

Comment: Helle @player0, thank you for your proposal but it is not working. Sorry about that ! I changed my request : now I show my entire script. This can help to resolve my interrogations...